# How to check if application is blocked by firewall

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

I can't update my NetBeans, even though the windows firewall and proxy settings are ok. Is there a logfile so I can find out if my application is getting blocked, or is there another way to detect if a firewall is the cause?

I know I could try to disable my MC Afee, but this would be dangerous and im not allowed to.

Comment: Answered here [How do I access a firewall log (Windows 10 w. Windows Defender)](//security.stackexchange.com/q/166875)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot update NetBeans (or any other product) through its interface,
the usual solution is to download the full installation file
corresponding to the latest version of NetBeans.

Executing the installation file will upgrade NetBeans to that version.

Comment: I was unable to find the patch file.

Comment: Not the patch file : full installation file.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest installation file and it still says that there is a patch available.

Comment: Which version are you downloading, and are you sure that the patch is for NetBeans and not some add-on?

Comment: I am downloading 8.2 from here: https://netbeans.org/downloads/, I downloaded from "all". I found out about the patch in "Help -> About". It says: `Updates available to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2`

Comment: NetBeans is since January 2018 undergoing conversion to the Apache Incubator. The latest 8.2 releases are [here](NetBeans IDE 8.2 Download), but a new 9.0 release will be released [here](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). If you have downloaded the latest 8.2 release from the same link as mine, then it probably already includes all the patches that will be released for that version, and I suppose that you can ignore that update message until 9.0 is released.